# Play facebook videos(Using iFrame) on full screen in ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ipad, uiwebview

I'm showing Facebook videos in a universal app, everything works perfect in iphone but on ipad it doesn't work in full screen. My requirement is to show videos in full screen.

here's my code:

```
 NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=%@;' frameborder='0' width='%f' height='%f' allowfullscreen>",_selectedVideo.video_id,_videoView.frame.size.width,_videoView.frame.size.height];
 UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.videoView.frame.size.width, self.videoView.frame.size.height)];
 webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = NO;

 webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
 [self.videoView addSubview:webview];
```

Comment: I have opened the Facebook video link in ipad safari and full screen option is not there as well. I think for ipad they don't allow videos to run in full screen.